Server error on multisite installation
Hi we have created a WP multisite as we want to run a small wholesale shop as well as a retail one.  So www.myshop.com is the main retail and www.myshop.com/wholesale is b2b.
We are getting a few issues with the /wholesale site. The server error log shows this
[Tue Oct 22 11:09:25.870052 2024] [autoindex:error] [pid 130694] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/custom/public_html/wholesale/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.php8,index.php7,index.php5,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.jp,index.phtml,index.shtml,index.xhtml,index.html,index.htm,index.js) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive, referer: https://myshop.com/wholesale/product/silver-leaf-drop-earrings/
If we put a copy of the index.php in the trade folder will that break the site or solve the issue?  Or do we need to point the subdomain to the root folder? At the moment the trade folder is empty. Please can anyone help?

This looks like more of an issue with how you set up your multi-site - have you double checked you .htaccess and wp-config.php files?
